# Please Explain Google talk's working as a p2p Application

Tags: p2p, google-talk

I was going through some article and found that chat Clients are mostly p2p. If Google Talk is a p2p client then how is it able to save our chat in Gmail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the audio is streamed from browser to browser without any server in between using the Jingle protocol.

So things like text chat and audio chat is peer-to-peer whereas all other functionality is provided by Google servers.

he chat it self uses Jabber (XMPP), but conversation logs are automatically saved to a Chats area in the user's Gmail account. This means that chats involve three parties (your computer, your mates computer and Googles Gmail server cluster)